# How to write URLs in Latex?

Tags: url, latex, text-formatting

How do you write a URL in Latex?

The subscripts and everything else make the font look very strange when it compiles.

Comment: Plus if there are any `_`s in your URLs, Latex will not be nice to you.

Answer (score 329):

You can use `\url`

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\url{http://stackoverflow.com/}
```

Comment: Is there a way to escape special characters like `&` or `_` automatically, when its part of the url? Those characters are often getting used in URLs as separator for dynamic values.

Comment: Much better: `\href{https://example.com}{links label}`

Comment: it doesnt show the second tag \url, what to do?

Answer (score 59):

You just need to escape characters that have special meaning: `# $ % & ~ _ ^ \ { }`

So

`http://stack_overflow.com/~foo%20bar#link`

would be

`http://stack\_overflow.com/\~foo\%20bar\#link`

Comment: The `\verb` command is much less work than that!

Comment: The only problem with `\verb` is that it uses a typewriter font. I would have suggested `\verbatim` if that's what he asked for.

Comment: As Gabe and Charles point out, the hyperref package is very good at wrapping URLs that would otherwise cause unsightly overfull hboxes.

Comment: This does not work correctly for me. For example, `\url{https://asdfg.com\#123}` produces `#` in text, however, the actual link it produces is `https://asdfg.com%23123`.

Answer (score 49):

Here is all the information you need in order to format clickable hyperlinks in LaTeX:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks

Essentially, you use the `hyperref` package and use the `\url` or `\href` tag depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 28):

A minimalist implementation of the `\url` macro that uses only Tex primitives:

```
\def\url#1{\expandafter\string\csname #1\endcsname}
```

This url absolutely won't break over lines, though; the [hypperef](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package is better for that.